# angularJS input number - error if no number

Tags: angularjs

I have this input field:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control zip" name="postalCode" data-ng-mode
```

and actually these checks:

```
<div class="errorMessage col-sm-offset-0" data-ng-show="createContactForm.postalCode.$error.minlength && !createContactForm.postalCode.$pristine">...</div>
<div class="errorMessage col-sm-offset-0" data-ng-show="createContactForm.postalCode.$error.maxlength && !createContactForm.postalCode.$pristine">...</div>
```

Is there also a check if no number is entered into number input field?

Comment: Add the `required` attribute, and check for the $error.required error?

Comment: @JB: I was going to say it, I think you can post it as an answer :)